# How can I see why points were deducted?

Tags: support

Just noticed I got a -2 on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985930/50-000-rows-created-when-querying-small-table-in-google-sheets-working-as-desig) 1 hour ago. Is there a way for me to see why/what I did wrong so I can avoid a potential mistake next time?

Answer (score 4):

Go to the reputation tab on your profile - it will show what post got downvoted.

However, that doesn't guarantee that anyone posted a comment explaining why they downvoted (we don't require that, for various reasons).

Looking at your profile, you have a single question that has been closed as off-topic. Posting an off-topic question can certainly get people to downvote it.

I suggest reading our help center articles - in particular [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [our good question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: That was quick! Ok. So as far as I can see the question is not close as off-topic, but "on hold" as off-topic. However, after this happened,a user with with a 6,403 posted a comment that is basically an answer to the question,

Comment: Glad someone helped you. But this isn't a programming question (it is about google spreadsheet usage), so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. A question that is on-hold for a few days will end up closed - I don't see this getting out of the on-hold state, given that it is off-topic.

Comment: 2nd try:That was quick! Ok. So as far as I can see the question is not close as off-topic, but "on hold" as off-topic. However, after this happened,a user with a 156,799 commented that he couldn't really see why it was off-topic ("...Personally, I don't see why it shouldn't be on SO. Excel questions get asked here every day and no-one moves them to SU.)". Also a user with 6,403 posted a comment that IMO contains a substansive answer to the question. Imo it is quite possible he would have posted this as an answer, if this would not have been prevented by the question already being on hold.

Comment: So 2 questions I guess: I can request a move/move it to SU myself, and will this remove the "on hold" status? I still feel it is a question and comment that add value, and me (nor others so far) have been able to find a duplicate question so far.

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators to migrate to SU (they might not).

Comment: Ok thank you; just flagged the question and asked for review of off-topicness and requested move to SU, with explanation.

Comment: Question was moved to SU shortly after requesting the move.